# Split indirect question

Tags: grammar, questions, embedding, noun-classes

Here's a direct question.

> Where does he live?

And here's an indirect one.

> Do you know *where he lives*?

I wonder how you would analyze the following structure. Can we call it "a split indirect question/noun clause"?

> *Where* do you think *he lives*?

Comment: Please define what you mean by indirect question.

Comment: @Lambie: an embedded question

Comment: Right, Thanks. For me, "Do you know where he lives?" is not an embedded ot indirect question. The question is composed of the question element: "Do you know" followed by dependent clause with the word where introducing it. –

Comment: @Lambie: "We can ask a question indirectly by putting it into a sub-clause beginning with a question word or with _if/whether_. This makes the question sound less abrupt. _We need to know what the rules are. Could you tell me where Queen Street is, please? Do you know when the train gets in?_" John Eastwood, _Oxford Learner's Grammar_, p. 26 "We can ask an **indirect question** by putting it into a **subordinate** CLAUSE beginning with a WH-WORD or with _if_ or _whether_ (e.g. Can you tell me _where you live_?)." Martin Hewings, _Advanced Grammar in Use_, p. 215

Comment: As I said, there is nothing indirect in "Do you know [etc.]. The fact the sub-clause has other information does not make it indirect, regardless of what Brainly says. **Can you tell me* where you live? It is  interrogative because of "Can you tell me [etc.]" not because of "where you live".

Comment: However, I said to him , "do you know where he lives" change into indirect speech.​ (from Brainly) becomes in indirect **speech**: Do  you know where he lives? That is called indirect speech or reported speech.

Comment: Can you please respond to my last two comments? Thanks.

Comment: @Lambie: "The example comes from Brainly, I think." They're my own examples and explanations. More reference works where such questions are classified as _indirect questions_: "_Can you tell me whether or not you’re interested in the job?_" [If and whether: indirect questions - Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/if-or-whether) "All the **wh-** words (including **whether**) can introduce INDIRECT QUESTIONS. _Can you tell me **what the time is**, please?_" Geoffrey Leech, _An A-Z of English Grammar & Usage_, p. 578

Comment: Your link says this: We can use if or whether to report indirect yes-no questions and questions with or. If is more common than whether. That is neither of yours. It would have to be: Do you know if/whether he lives here? For example.